# Why Chart.js are not rendering scaleLabels?

Tags: chart.js

I have strange problem trying to display labels for X-axis and Y-axis.
I check the same code for my charts in CodeSandbox, it works fine. But in my project it doesn't work...I have empty areas instead text labels.

I have several chunks of options for different types of charts. In options for showing labels  I have:

```
scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: initialLabels.y_label,
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      ],
      xAxes: [
        {
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: initialLabels.x_label,
          },

          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```

I logged **initialLabels.x_label** and **initialLabels.y_label**, **its OK!** What type of problem it can be?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors ?

Comment: @HMZ the problem is I don't have any console errors...I don't know how I can look under the hood of chart.js  functions

Comment: If its working in CodeSandbox my first guess would be that your framework has something to do with it or you have a corrupt dependency try loading Chart.js from another CDN or maybe its a width and height issue that causing the labels not to show?

Comment: @HMZ Thank you for your advise.I haven't  solved that problem yet. Try different ways: CDN, npm packets or standalone files and change canvas size by different ways. Maybe, problem in my code. Hope, I will find solution:)

Comment: Same issue, did you solve this?